# Group by object attribute in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

I have a simple class:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name} [{self.age} yrs old]'
```

which I use to store an list of `Person` instances in a pandas data frame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

people = []
people.append(Person(name='alex', age=20))
people.append(Person(name='daisy', age=20))
people.append(Person(name='john', age=30))
people.append(Person(name='alex', age=40))
cities = ['London', 'Edinburgh', 'London', 'Edinburgh']
data = dict(people=people, cities=cities)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

**Is there any way to group the `data_frame` by `people.age`, for e.g.?**

**EDIT**

Doing something like this:

```
df.groupby('people.age').groups
```

would output something like this:

```
{'20': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'), '30': Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'), '40': Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')}
```

Comment: please post the output what you are looking for

Comment: @mohan111 See edit, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` really isn't meant to store objects. You have a class with attributes, which with pandas are better organized in a 2D stucture (1 row per Person, with columns for each individual attribute).

The issue with holding classes is that we need to resort to a very slow `Series.apply` in order to do anything. The syntax can still be concise, but the performance is horrible.

In your case we use `getattr`.

```
df.groupby(df.people.apply(lambda x: getattr(x, 'age'))).groups
#{20: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
# 30: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
# 40: Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')}
```

---

I'd instead recommend the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in people]).assign(cities=cities)
#   age   name     cities
#0   20   alex     London
#1   20  daisy  Edinburgh
#2   30   john     London
#3   40   alex  Edinburgh

df.groupby('age').groups
#{20: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
# 30: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
# 40: Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')}
```